# Sharing resources in Twitter/Apache Storm

Tags: java, twitter, stream, apache-storm

I'm using the storm architecture, and I've got a bolt which spawns 5 threads(/tasks, as far as I can tell they're an interchangeable term).

Is there a way for me to set a variable which all threads can read and write to?

Thanks :).

Comment: A task in a thread running inside a worker, it can only share a variable with other threads within the same JVM (although ideally it should not). Keep in mind that you have plenty of tasks sitting on plenty of workers running in plenty of nodes, the only way to make them share something is via some kind of external persistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For understanding parallelism in Storm (and what tasks, executors, workers means), I recommend: [Understanding the parallelism of a Storm topology](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html).

In your Bolt, you can have a shared resource (like an instance variable of a Bolt) but you need to synchronise access to it, otherwise you will be in a deep trouble (unsurprisingly). But that shared resource isn't going to be shared between different Bolts.

Comment: Not 100% sure if this still holds, but according to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/IS8PijLjU8c the bolts don't need to be thread safe. That implies to me that instance variables would not be shared between bolts (static class variables would be shared by all the instances of a bolt on a given worker). I think, if you are trying to read/write to a single variable from many bolts you may want to take a step back and reconsider what you're doing. take a look at field groupings for example, they may provide the functionality you really want

Comment: Nimbus will create all the bolt threads, serialize them, and send to the appropriate worker, so bolt threads are independent and resources are deep copyed. Each task on a worker has their own instance of the bolt or spout. So we can't have a shared resource between tasks or bolts

Comment: If there is reference to a static variable of a class on a bolt. The value of the static variable will be available every time a new tuple is processed on a task assigned for this bolt. Is that correct.